# Download large files from GitHub

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I am trying to download SAR ship detection dataset from https://github.com/CAESAR-Radi/SAR-Ship-Dataset.

However when I click on the dataset file, here's what I get:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:cfc04a1c41fe8f36676bdbf4bd6a4c2816580daa09cad4b61f6ce5b4a38abb2a
size 494944019
```

I want to know how do I download this (ship_detection_online.rar) dataset using the above info.

Comment: did you try cloning the repo ?

Comment: yes, dosent work

Comment: Even I get error. It says "This repository is over its data quota. Account responsible for LFS bandwidth should purchase more data packs to restore access". If this is the error you are getting, it essentially means that the particular repo has exhausted it bandwidth quota. More info here : https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage. You can check the logs at SAR-Ship-Dataset\.git\lfs\logs\